# Creating a loop to add labels to colums: library(Hmisc)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, label, hmisc

I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
  Year      Country  Matchcode  P             H
1 2000      France        0001  1213          1872     
2 2001      France        0002  1234          2345      
3 2000      UK            0003  1726          2234      
4 2001      UK            0004  6433          9082
```

I have another dataset which looks something like this:

```
Indicator Code  Indicator Name
P               Power
H               Happiness
```

I would like to add info in the second column of the second dataset (Power, Happiness) as a label to the abbreviation used in the first dataset with a loop, but I don't know exactly how to write the loop.

This is how far I got:

```
library(Hmisc)
for i in df2[,1]{
if (df1[,i] == df2[i,]){
label(df1[,i]) <- df2[i,2]
}}
```

But this merely checks whether names are the same and does not search for it.
Could anyone guide further?

Desired output:

[image]

```
  Year      Country  Matchcode  P(label=Power) H(label=Happiness)
1 2000      France        0001            1213              1872     
2 2001      France        0002            1234              2345      
3 2000      UK            0003            1726              2234      
4 2001      UK            0004            6433              9082
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you simply want to add `label = Power` and `label = Happiness` to the column names `P` and `H`, respectively? I don't understand what you're trying to do with `Hmisc::label`. `Hmisc::label` simply sets/reads the `label` attribute of a variable. Column names are plain `character` vectors.

Comment: colnames(df[4:5]) <- c('P(label=Power)', 'H(label=Happiness)') ; would give you the ouput. Not sure this is what you need.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Haha, I am sorry, I am apparently quite poor at explaining. Well actually I just want to add Power as a label to P, Happiness as a label to H and so on.. I know it does not make much sense in this example, but itis extremely useful for my actual dataset

Comment: @milan Thank you for your answer. I am looking for a bit more general solution. The actual dataset has about 1600 variables.

Comment: Does your second dataset have column names?

Comment: @TomKisters So then this has in fact nothing to do with `Hmisc::label`? And you just want to programmatically add a string to certain columns based on data from a second `data.frame`?

Comment: @ AntoniosK Yes it does (Indicator Name, and Indicator Code)

Comment: @MauritsEvers I was under the impression that I need that package to add labels like exlained here: https://www.statmethods.net/input/variablelables.html

Comment: @TomKisters `Hmisc::label(x)` adds an **attribute** to specific objects (which you can check with `attributes(x)`). It seems to me all you want to do is change column names for certain columns (based on a lookup). Does AntoniosK's answer below do what you're after?

Comment: @MauritsEvers No, it needs to be the actual labels. The problem is that the actual names(and even codes) are very long. I want to keep the column names short while still being able to see what the code stands for.

Comment: @TomKisters that links mentions "Unfortunately the label is only in effect for functions provided by the Hmisc package". So, if you actually want to use the column names with the labels you have to properly update the names. If the codes are long you have to apply a process to shorten them and use the short labels.

Comment: @TomKisters As I explained in an early comment, the vector of column names of a `data.frame` is a `character` vector. It cannot have attributes.

Comment: @TomKisters I've added an example below to illustrate; please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically want to use a loop, this approach gives the output you describe:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
                 Country = c("France", "France", "UK","UK"),
                 Matchcode = c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004"),
                 P = c(1213, 1234, 1726, 6433),
                 H = c(1872, 2345, 2234, 9082))

lookup <- data.frame(code = c ("P", "H"),
                     label = c("Power", "Happiness"),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
  if(!is.na(match(colnames(df), lookup$code)[i])) {
    Hmisc::label(df[[i]]) <- lookup$label[(match(colnames(df), lookup$code))[i]]
  }
}
```

This works:

```
Hmisc::label(df[4])
#       P 
# "Power"
```

It also checks out in the RStudio viewer:

[image: Screen shot of RStudio object viewer showing the variables with Hmisc labels, as desired.]

Like several of the other answerers and commenters, I had originally thought you wanted to append the "label = " text to the column names. For anyone wanting that, this is the (loop) code.

```
for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
  if(!is.na(match(colnames(df), lookup$code)[i])) {
    colnames(df)[i] <- paste0(colnames(df)[i],
                              "(label=",
                              lookup$label[(match(colnames(df), lookup$code))[i]],
                              ")")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do with `Hmisc::label` but I think you're misinterpreting the role & function of `Hmisc::label`.

Consider the following:

1. Let's construct a sample `data.frame` consisting of 2 rows and 2 columns.

   ```
   df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)), c("a", "b"))
   df
   #  a b
   #1 0 0
   #2 0 0
   ```
2. We extract the column names. **Note that `cn` is a `character` vector.**

   ```
   cn <- colnames(df)
   cn
   #[1] "a" "b"
   ```
3. We now set a `Hmisc::label` for `cn`.

   ```
   label(cn) <- "label for cn"
   cn
   #label for cn
   #[1] "a" "b"
   ```

   We inspect the `attributes` of `cn`

   ```
   attributes(cn)
   #$label
   #[1] "label for cn"
   #
   #$class
   #[1] "labelled"  "character"
   ```
4. We now assign `cn` to the column names of `df`.

   ```
   colnames(df) <- cn
   df
   #  a b
   #1 0 0
   #2 0 0
   ```

**Note how the `label` attribute is not stored as part of the column names.**

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate explanation. I understand that the labels are not stored as part of the column names; They are however normally visible in the Rstudio viewer. In addition, I just figured out that the labels actually did not go lost in the `left_join` but with a mutation: `df <-  df%>%
 group_by(country) %>%
 mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(d = . - lag(.)))` The new mutated variables then do no longer have labels, the old ones do ( I am really sorry for just figuring this out now).

Comment: I have added a picture to be more clear in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
# example datasets
df = read.table(text = "
Year      Country  Matchcode  P             H
1 2000      France        0001  1213          1872     
2 2001      France        0002  1234          2345      
3 2000      UK            0003  1726          2234      
4 2001      UK            0004  6433          9082 
", header=T)

df2 = read.table(text = "
IndicatorName IndicatorCode
P    Power
H    Happiness 
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

data.frame(original_names = names(df)) %>%                     # get original names
  left_join(df2, by=c("original_names"="IndicatorName")) %>%   # join names that should be updated
  mutate(new_names = ifelse(is.na(IndicatorCode), original_names, paste0(original_names,"(label=",IndicatorCode,")"))) %>%  # if there is a match update the name
  pull(new_names) -> list_new_names                            # get column of new names and store it in a vector

# update names
names(df) = list_new_names

# check new names
df

#   Year Country Matchcode P(label=Power) H(label=Happiness)
# 1 2000  France         1           1213               1872
# 2 2001  France         2           1234               2345
# 3 2000      UK         3           1726               2234
# 4 2001      UK         4           6433               9082
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work. Find the corresponding text using `%in%`, and use `paste0` to generate the label.

```
colnames(df1)[4:5] <- paste0(colnames(df1)[4:5], '(label=', df2$V2[colnames(df1)[4:5] %in% df2$V1], ')')

df1

Year Country Matchcode P(label=Power) H(label=Happiness)
1 2000  France         1           1213               1872
2 2001  France         2           1234               2345
3 2000      UK         3           1726               2234
4 2001      UK         4           6433               9082
```

**Data used**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Year      Country  Matchcode  P             H
1 2000      France        0001  1213          1872     
2 2001      France        0002  1234          2345      
3 2000      UK            0003  1726          2234      
4 2001      UK            0004  6433          9082", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F) 

df2 <- read.table(text="
P    Power
H    Happiness", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this but it does not actually add labels to the column names. I added a picture to my original post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you still stick with Hmisc, you can modify the 'print' function to handle the extra information provided by the labels, or rather (and less harmfull) says to R that your data has to be printed using the labels. You can achieve this by creating a new data frame class for which the print function behaves differently.

The 'print' trick is not necessary with Rstudio that natively uses the labels together with the column names.

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
  Year      Country  Matchcode  P             H
1 2000      France        0001  1213          1872     
2 2001      France        0002  1234          2345      
3 2000      UK            0003  1726          2234      
4 2001      UK            0004  6433          9082  ", header=T)
df2 = read.table(text = "
var  lab
P    Power
H    Happiness", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Set the labels of the columns in df1 accordingly to df2
library(Hmisc)
for (i in 1:ncol(df1)) {
    lab <- df2[df2$var==colnames(df1)[i],2]
    if (length(lab!=0)) label(df1[[i]]) <- lab
}

# A print' function dedicated to 'truc' objects
# Mainly it is the code from the original 'print' except for dimnames[[2L]]
print.truc <- function (x, ..., digits = NULL, quote = FALSE, right = TRUE, 
row.names = TRUE) 
  {
  n <- length(row.names(x))
  if (length(x) == 0L) {
    cat(sprintf(ngettext(n, "data frame with 0 columns and %d row", 
        "data frame with 0 columns and %d rows"), n), "\n", 
        sep = "")
    }    
    else if (n == 0L) {
        print.default(names(x), quote = FALSE)
        cat(gettext("<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)\n"))
    }
    else {
        m <- as.matrix(format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, 
            na.encode = FALSE))
        if (!isTRUE(row.names)) 
            dimnames(m)[[1L]] <- if (isFALSE(row.names)) 
                rep.int("", n)
                else row.names
        dimnames(m)[[2L]] <- purrr::map(1:ncol(x),
           function(i) {
             z <- attributes(x[[i]])$label
             if (length(z)!=0) z else colnames(x)[i]
           })
        print(m, ..., quote = quote, right = right)
      }
      invisible(x)
   }

# Says that 'df1' is an 'enhanced' data frame
class(df1) <- c("truc",class(df1))

# Print as enhanced
print(df1)
#  Eyra Country Matchcode Power Happiness
#1 2000  France         1  1213      1872
#2 2001  France         2  1234      2345
#3 2000      UK         3  1726      2234
#4 2001      UK         4  6433      9082

# Print using standard way
print(as.data.frame(df1))
#  Year Country Matchcode    P    H
#1 2000  France         1 1213 1872
#2 2001  France         2 1234 2345
#3 2000      UK         3 1726 2234
#4 2001      UK         4 6433 9082
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop with `Hmisc`, can do this in one line using the option `self = FALSE` in the label command.

```
label(df1[, df2$IndicatorName], self = FALSE) <- df2$IndicatorCode
```

Ie.

```r
  
  library(Hmisc, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE)
  
  df1 = read.table(text = "
Year      Country  Matchcode  P             H
1 2000      France        0001  1213          1872     
2 2001      France        0002  1234          2345      
3 2000      UK            0003  1726          2234      
4 2001      UK            0004  6433          9082 
", header=T)
  
  df2 = read.table(text = "
IndicatorName IndicatorCode
P    Power
H    Happiness 
", header=T)
  
  
  label(df1[, df2$IndicatorName], self = FALSE) <- df2$IndicatorCode
  
  sapply(df1, label)
#>        Year     Country   Matchcode           P           H 
#>          ""          ""          ""     "Power" "Happiness"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>